# Ruby On Rails : Unpermitted parameters with has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many

Hello everyone,
I've been searching through stackoverflow but didn't find an answer yet so i'm asking directly.

I have a a simple table named message which contains a user id, and a content. I have now a second and a third table which contains the message_id from the message table, a recipient_id and a visibility.

When i submit the form, i always have the same error : Unpermitted parameters: message_recipients, message_groups. Even if i add them in the permit...

Let me show you :

**Message.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tenantable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :message_recipients
  has_many :message_groups

  validates :content, :user, presence: true

  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

**message_recipient.rb**

```
class MessageRecipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
end
```

**message_group.rb**

```
class MessageGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group
  belongs_to :message
end
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /messages/new
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  # POST /messages
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.message_recipients.empty?
        format.html { render :new}
      else
        if @message.save
          @message.message_recipients.user = current_user
          @message.message_recipients.message = @message

          format.html { redirect_to authenticated_root_path, notice: t('messages.created') }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content, { message_recipient_ids: [], message_group_ids: [] })
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<% if @message.errors.any? %>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span> <%= t('activerecord.errors.record_invalid', count: @message.errors.count) %></h4>
  <ul>
  <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= form_for(@message, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :message_recipients, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <%= f.select :message_recipients, options_for_select(User.all.map { |s|[s.firstname + ' ' + s.lastname, s.id] }) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :message_groups, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <%= f.select :message_groups, options_for_select(UserGroup.all.map { |s|[s.name, s.id] }) %>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :content, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><%= t('actions.save') %></button>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, change your field names to match what you've permitted in your controller.

`:message_recipients` to `":message_recipient_ids"`

Comment: Still not working... I've changed permit to something like params.require(:message).permit(:content, :message_recipients => []) but still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Here, that should do the trick. Not exactly the best solution, but still a valid one

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /messages/new
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  # POST /messages
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.user = current_user

    if @message.message_recipients.empty?
      format.html { render :new}
    else
      if @message.save
        create_message_recipients
        create_message_groups

        format.html { redirect_to authenticated_root_path, notice: t('messages.created') }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content)
  end

  def create_message_recipients
    params[:message][:message_recipients].each do |user_id|
      MessageRecipient.create(user_id: user_id, message_id: @message.id)
    end
  end

  def create_message_groups
    params[:message][:message_groups].each do |group_id|
      MessageGroup.create(group_id: group_id, message_id: @message.id)
    end
  end
end
```